# How can I improve performance of string processing with less memory?

Tags: java, string, performance, collections

I'm implementing this in Java.

```
Symbol file     Store data file

1\item1         10\storename1
10\item20       15\storename6
11\item6        15\storename9
15\item14       1\storename250
5\item5         1\storename15
```

The user will search store names using wildcards like `storename?`
My job is to search the store names and produce a full string using symbol data. For example:

item20-storename1
item14-storename6
item14-storename9

My approach is:

1. reading the store data file line by line
2. if any line contains matching search string (like `storename?`), I will push that line to an intermediate store result file
3. I will also copy the itemno of a matching storename into an arraylist (like 10,15)
4. when this arraylist size%100==0 then I will remove duplicate item no's using hashset,  reducing arraylist size significantly
5. when arraylist size >1000

   1. sort that list using `Collections.sort(itemno_arraylist)`
   2. open symbol file & start reading line by line
   3. for each line `Collections.binarySearch(itemno_arraylist,itmeno)`
   4. if matching then push result to an intermediate symbol result file
6. continue with step1 until EOF of store data file

...

After all of this I would combine two result files (symbol result file & store result file) to present actual strings list.

This approach is working but it is consuming more CPU time and main memory.

I want to know a better solution with reduced CPU time (currently 2 min) & memory (currently 80MB). There are many collection classes available in Java. Which one would give a more efficient solution for this kind of huge string processing problem?

If you have any thoughts on this kind of string processing problems that too in Java would be great and helpful.

Note: Both files would be nearly a million lines long.

Comment: Is your data file static or its changing frequently?

Comment: @Yogendra Singh Yes It will change but not frequently

Comment: Databases were created to solve such problems, y'know?

Answer (score 4):

Replace the two flat files with an embedded database (there's [plenty of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database), I used SQLite and Db4O in the past): problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to replace `10\storename1` with `item20-storename1` because the symbol file contains `10\item20`. The obvious solution is to load the symbol file into a Map:

```
String tokens=symbolFile.readLine().split("\\");
map.put(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
```

Then read the store file line by line and replace:

```
String tokens=storelFile.readLine().split("\\");
output.println(map.get(tokens[0])+'-'+tokens[1]));
```

This is the fastest method, though still using a lot of memory for the map. You can reduce the memory storing the map in a database, but this would increase the time significantly.

Answer (score 0):

If your input data file is not changing frequently, then parse the file once, put the data into a `List` of custom class e.g. `FileStoreRecord` mapping your record in the file. Define a `equals` method on your custom class. Perform all next steps over the `List` e.g. for search, you can call `contains` method by passing search string in form of the custom object `FileStoreRecord` .

If the file is changing after some time, you may want to refresh the `List` after certain interval or keep the track of list creation time and compare against the file update timestamp before using it. If ifferent, recreate the list. One other way to manage the file check could be to have a Thread continuously polling the file update and the moment, it is updated, it notifies to refresh the list.

Comment: I don't think this would be good because it will be only a bigger inner array. Note that OP doesn't access the elements with a `s1.equals(s2)` search.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any limitation to use Map?
You can add Items to Map, then you can search easily?
1 million record means 1M * recordSize, therefore it will not be problem.

```
   Map<Integer,Item> itemMap= new HashMap();
   ...
   Item item= itemMap.get(store.getItemNo());
```

But, the best solution will be with Database.